# android can i play .SWF as splash screen?

Tags: android

i have a video with .swf extension i don't know exactly how can i load it in the start of my application i have a sample code of splash video but i don't know how to use it and i don't know if it works with .SWF can i have your help

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    video.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ontouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        }) ;
```

Comment: SWF is Flash animation. First convert it to a video Android can play natively.

Comment: **Thank you for your fast responding but of what extension of video ??**

Comment: Android can play .MP4 views natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think to use it would be to have a `WebView` with the .swf embedded, but not all devices have (or support) Flash and it is being discontinued.
Expanding on user1093822's comment, if you convert it to a video you can use a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) to show it. A list of compatible extensions can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)